# Error during webSocket handshake unexpected response code: 400

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, mean-stack

i try to implement `cluster` in my `node` app with `socket.io`. if i not using `cluster` everything is working good. but when i use `cluster` its occur following error in client browser.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=Ff8LkaCbF5g92lKOAAAS' failed: Error during WebSocket 
socket.js:2 POST http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MAjySbD&sid=Ff8LkaCbF5g92lKOAAAS 400 (Bad Request)
```

here is server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('../app');
cluster = module.exports = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var server = http.createServer(app);
io = module.exports = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
    pingTimeout: 7000,
    pingInterval: 10000
});
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling","websocket","polling"]);
if(cluster.isMaster){
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    });

} else {
    var port = 8000;
    var  host = '0.0.0.0';
    server.listen(port,host,function(){
        log('server is running on ' + host +':'+port);
    });
}
```

here is the client.js

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/dashboard',{transports: ['websocket']});
```

Comment: On what host your server is running?

Comment: yes server is running on global host.

Comment: In your clientJs you are connecting it to localhost , Which might be the problem I think

Comment: No, i think this is not problem, because i just remove cluster and its working.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you using `express-status-monitor` as a middleware on express, this makes http call on the first (request) handshake of WebSocket goes failed, or maybe another factor like proxy (nginx) or similar like that

Look [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942) for more details about this error

Comment: thanks a lot, you are really an experienced programmer...!